# Enabling 32-bit Applications in IIS7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I want to enable 32-bit applications in my app pool. What kind of bad things can happen? Why is it off?

I tried it, and a few things look fine, but I don't want some hidden portion of the site be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is off by default because you only need it if you are using 32bit components (such as COM objects) in your app.  It is not needed for pure .NET applications and I'm going to guess that enabling it will cause the memory footprint and startup time for IIS to increase by a non-trivial amount.  But I don't think there is any noticeable difference, so if you need 32bit support for a legacy application reason, go ahead and enable it.